# number of times value occur on an array mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a data set like this

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5a1414430b4215041c768f50"),
   "slug" : [ 
      "a", "b", "c"
   ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1414430b4215041c768f51"),
    "slug" : [ 
        "a", "d", "e"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1414430b4215041c768f52"),
    "slug" : [ 
        "b", "b", "f"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1414430b4215041c768f53"),
    "slug" : [ 
        "g", "h", "b"
    ]
}
```

So Here on this, array  store strings. Now I want to calculate that on the entire data set, Values of slug repeated how many times. For example: After my database query the desired result will be like

```
a = 2, b = 4, c = 1, d = 1, e = 1, f = 1, g = 1, h = 1
```

I am using Aggregation for doing this kind of task but not able to exactly get the desired result.
my Query is

```
Message.aggregate([
            {"$project": {"slug":1}},
            {"$unwind":"$slug"},
            {"$group": {"_id":{"_id":"$_id", "slug":"$slug"}, "count":{"$sum":1}}},
            {"$match": {"count":{"$gt":1}}},
            {"$group": {"_id": "$_id._id", "slug":{"$addToSet":"$_id.slug"}}}
        ]);
```

This Query returns data only when any string found.
Please guide me that where I am doing mistake. Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done it by yourself, in other words you have crossed the result which you require. Just use the below query to get the desired result

```
db.Message.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$slug"},
    {$group:{"_id":"$slug", "count":{"$sum":1}}}
]);
```

The result on the sample documents shown in question is as shown below

```
{ "_id" : "h", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "g", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "f", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "e", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "b", "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "d", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "c", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "a", "count" : 2 }
```

To make the result printed in sorted manner use $sort

```
db.Message.aggregate([
   {$unwind:"$slug"},
   {$group:{"_id":"$slug", "count":{"$sum":1}}},
   {$sort:{"_id":1}}
]);
```

We have use ascending order on `_id' and the Sorted result is

```
{ "_id" : "a", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "b", "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "c", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "d", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "e", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "f", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "g", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "h", "count" : 1 }
```

> Is there any solution to get my slug value to custom field rather than
>   under _id. Like `{ "slugname" : "a", "count" : 2 }` instead of `{ "_id" : "a", "count" : 2 }`

This can be done by adding [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to the existing query

_id:0 - will suppress it to the next stage

slugname :"$_id" - Will add the value of _id to slugname

```
db.Message.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$slug"}, 
    {$group:{"_id":"$slug", "count":{"$sum":1}}},
    {$sort:{"_id":1}}, 
    {$project: {_id:0, slugname :"$_id", count:"$count"}}
]);
```

final result

```
{ "slugname" : "a", "count" : 2 }
{ "slugname" : "b", "count" : 4 }
{ "slugname" : "c", "count" : 1 }
{ "slugname" : "d", "count" : 1 }
{ "slugname" : "e", "count" : 1 }
{ "slugname" : "f", "count" : 1 }
{ "slugname" : "g", "count" : 1 }
{ "slugname" : "h", "count" : 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot #Clement Amarnath

Comment: Is there any solution to get my slug value to custom field rather than under _id. Like { "slugname" : "a", "count" : 2 } instead of { "_id" : "a", "count" : 2 }.

Comment: Anyway, the `_id` column is mandatory here, see the document [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Comment: @Iron_Man and @DavidWei - `{ "slugname" : "a", "count" : 2 }` instead of `{ "_id" : "a", "count" : 2 }`, this can be done using the $project in the aggregation pipeline, please see the updated answer.

Comment: Once again Thanks a Lot @clement-amarnath